# Apple iPod 16gb; Can this be used without the internet?

Tags: ipod

Can I use my iPod outside in the yard without the internet? I will buying one for Christmas and would like to know.

Answer (score 8):

Yes.  You can use your iPod/iPad/iPhone without Internet.

As long as whatever you are doing doesn't require an Internet connection, you will be fine.

For instance, if you are listening to music that you sync'd from your computer or downloaded from iTunes, it will work.  You can even play a number of games without an Internet connection.

However, **streaming services** like Pandora, Spotify, and Netflix will not work.

Comment: For clarify - it requires internet to download songs, but once they are on the device, you do not need internet to listen to those songs. (streaming and other lingo may confuse some folks).

Comment: For clarify - you can put songs from your computer on your iPhone without having to download.